# How to return a list as a dictionary, with the placement of the lists' variables as the dictionary's values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

For example, in a race, I have a list of runners and their names in a list ordered from their places, such as `['Bob', 'Charlie', 'Sarah', 'Alex', 'Bob']`
I want to create a dictionary with this list such as

```
{'Bob': [0, 4], 'Charlie': [1], 'Sarah': [2], 'Alex': [3]}
```

If you only need to create a dictionary with the list variables as the dictionary keys and the positions of the lists' variables as the dictionary values, how would you do so?

```
[A, B, C, A] -> {A: [0, 3] B: [1], C:[2]}
```

(I'm having trouble figuring this out.)

Thank you. Sorry for the changed output. Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll lose information about one of the `Bob`'s since a `dict`'s keys are unique... Why do you need a dict - why is a `list` not sufficient?

Comment: after your edit , i edit the answer !

Comment: @Nicky I updated my answer with your changes

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumerate()`. This will iterate through the list, providing you with both the current element and that element's index.

```
my_list = ['Bob', 'Charlie', 'Sarah']
my_dict = {}
for index, name in enumerate(my_list):
    my_dict[name] = index
```

EDIT: Since the OP has changed.

To get exactly what you requested, you could use a `defaultdict`. This will create a `dict` and you specify what you want the *default* values to be. So if you go to access a key that does not yet exist, an empty list will automatically be added as the value. This way you can do the following:

```
from collections import defualtdict
my_list = ['Bob', 'Charlie', 'Sarah', 'Bob']
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for index, name in enumerate(my_list):
    my_dict[name].append(index)
```

Comment: Or as a dict-comp: `{name:idx for idx, name in enumerate(my_list)}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enumerate()` and [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> your_list=['A','B','C','C','A','A','B','D']
>>> l=[(j,i) for i,j in enumerate(your_list,1)]
>>> l
[('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('C', 4), ('A', 5), ('A', 6), ('B', 7), ('D', 8)]
>>> g=[list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l),itemgetter(0))]
>>> g
[[('A', 1), ('A', 5), ('A', 6)], [('B', 2), ('B', 7)], [('C', 3), ('C', 4)], [('D', 8)]]
>>> z=[zip(*i) for i in g]
>>> z
[[('A', 'A', 'A'), (1, 5, 6)], [('B', 'B'), (2, 7)], [('C', 'C'), (3, 4)], [('D',), (8,)]]
>>> {i[0]:j for i,j in z}
{'A': (1, 5, 6), 'C': (3, 4), 'B': (2, 7), 'D': (8,)}
```

Comment: You don't need the `i+1` - you can offset the `enumerate` instead..., eg: `enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C'], 1)`

Answer (score 0):

how about a simple loop to get the desired result:

```
x = ['Bob', 'Charlie', 'Sarah', 'Alex', 'Bob']
y = {}
for i, name in enumerate(x):
    if name in y.keys():
            y[name].append(i)
    else:
            y[name] = [i]
```